# While using Thread sleep on ParallelFlux its not waiting for sleep thread to get completed and executing onComplete() function

Tags: webclient, spring-webflux, flux, spring-webclient

1. While using Parallel on Flux i am stopping thread for some time using thread sleep, but the problem is that flux not waiting till thread sleep time and executed on onComplete on subscribe.

   List str = new ArrayList<>();
   str.add("spring");
   str.add("webflux");
   str.add("example");

   ```
               AtomicInteger num = new AtomicInteger();

               ParallelFlux<Object> names = Flux.fromIterable(str)
                       .log()
                       .parallel(2)
                       .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                       .map( s-> {

                           if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("webflux")) {
                               try {
                                   System.out.println("waiting...");
                                   Thread.sleep(1000);
                                   System.out.println("done...");
                               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                   e.printStackTrace();
                               }
                           }
                           return s+" "+num.incrementAndGet();

                       });

               names.subscribe(s -> {
                   System.out.println("value "+s+" thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
               });
   ```

Output:

```
    19:35:24.870 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Iterable.1 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxIterable.IterableSubscription)
19:35:24.896 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Iterable.1 - | request(256)
19:35:24.897 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Iterable.1 - | onNext(spring)
19:35:24.898 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Iterable.1 - | onNext(webflux)
19:35:24.898 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Iterable.1 - | onNext(example)
waiting...
value spring 1 thread : boundedElastic-1
value example 2 thread : boundedElastic-1
19:35:24.899 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Iterable.1 - | onComplete()
```